# io.realm.exceptions.RealmFileException: Invalid mnemonic. Error

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, realm

I faced this error

> io.realm.exceptions.RealmFileException: Unable to open a realm at path Invalid mnemonic."

I searched the internet to find that this is a open issue in realm-core as of now.I would like to ask two things-

1) I tried rerunning this following code every time the app opens and it fixed the issue for me. -

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .encryptionKey(key)
                .schemaVersion(0)
                .migration(new Migration())
                .build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

Is this is hotfix? Is there any better fix for this?

2) What is the realm mandated way to initialize the realm config? Do we rerun the above code every time our app opens or do we do that just once and use `Realm.setDefaultConfiguration` and a flag to see if it has been set or not?

The steps to reproduce and some details about my app are as under:-

1)The app opens for the first time where this code checks if default configuration needs to be set or not:

```
 boolean cond1 = mSharedPreferenceManager.checkKeyExistence(UtilityManager.IS_DEFAULT_CONFIG_INITIALISED,SharedPreferenceManager.USER_AUTH_STORE);

        if(!cond1) {
            RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                    .encryptionKey(key)
                    .schemaVersion(0)
                    .migration(new Migration())
                    .build();
            Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
            mSharedPreferenceManager.saveToPreferences(true, UtilityManager.IS_DEFAULT_CONFIG_INITIALISED, SharedPreferenceManager.USER_AUTH_STORE);
        }
```

Since I set the flag on the first install, the code above in the if block does not run the next time onwards.

2)When I open the app the next time, only `Realm.init(this);` runs and the code crashes with the mnemonic error.

Some salient details about realm usage in app-
Currently there is no migration happening in the app just an empty placeholder class. Only one realm db called default.realm exists.

Stacktrace below

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.app5, PID: 4419
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app5/com.example.app5.ui.MainActivity}: io.realm.exceptions.RealmFileException: Unable to open a realm at path '/data/data/com.example.app5/files/default.realm': Invalid mnemonic. top_ref[0]: D80ED9100000019C, top_ref[1]: CDD91816A436DE3C, mnemonic: B9 A4 9D 6E, fmt[0]: 41, fmt[1]: 206, flags: FE. (Invalid mnemonic. top_ref[0]: D80ED9100000019C, top_ref[1]: CDD91816A436DE3C, mnemonic: B9 A4 9D 6E, fmt[0]: 41, fmt[1]: 206, flags: FE) (/data/data/com.example.app5/files/default.realm) in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 101 Kind: ACCESS_ERROR.
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmFileException: Unable to open a realm at path '/data/data/com.example.app5/files/default.realm': Invalid mnemonic. top_ref[0]: D80ED9100000019C, top_ref[1]: CDD91816A436DE3C, mnemonic: B9 A4 9D 6E, fmt[0]: 41, fmt[1]: 206, flags: FE. (Invalid mnemonic. top_ref[0]: D80ED9100000019C, top_ref[1]: CDD91816A436DE3C, mnemonic: B9 A4 9D 6E, fmt[0]: 41, fmt[1]: 206, flags: FE) (/data/data/com.example.app5/files/default.realm) in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 101 Kind: ACCESS_ERROR.
>           at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm(Native Method)
>           at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.(OsSharedRealm.java:171)
>           at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.getInstance(OsSharedRealm.java:241)
>           at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.getInstance(OsSharedRealm.java:231)
>           at io.realm.RealmCache.doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:318)
>           at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:284)
>           at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java:407)
>           at com.example.app5.ui.MainActivity.populate(MainActivity.java:322)
>           at com.example.app5.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:225)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
>   2018-11-28 12:38:43.356 1844-1917/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'ba15b10 com.example.app5/com.example.app5.ui.SplashActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>   2018-11-28 12:38:43.441 2537-3071/? E/s.nexuslaunche: Failed to open APK '/data/app/com.example.app5-Ozu0pufh-sj1_M7EbxGkXA==/base.apk' I/O error
>   2018-11-28 12:38:43.441 2537-3071/? E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.example.app5-Ozu0pufh-sj1_M7EbxGkXA==/base.apk
>   2018-11-28 12:38:44.092 2805-2907/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded

Comment: Invalid mnemonic means the Realm is corrupted. I can't know why, so no advice there.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: Added some details to clarify the context. Please tell me if I can provide any other details pertaining to this crash, that would be helpful in solving this error.

Comment: @arb93 This crash occurs due to wrong Encryption key. Please check your encryption key.